# How to get a specific node name in an XML using XPath (using Groovy)

Tags: groovy

I have an XML as below:

```
String xml = """  
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <processAsyncRequest></processAsyncRequest>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>  
"""
```

Using Groovy, i want to find the first node name inside "Body" using XPath (//*:Body/*[1]/name())

```
Output Should be : processAsyncRequest
```

I am parsing the xml using XmlSlurper. But couldnt figure out the next steps to get node name using XPath

```
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this? Note : the structure of my xml changes every time. So i want to use Relative Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but that's not `XPath`. it's `GPath`

```
String xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='...'>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <processAsyncRequest></processAsyncRequest>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>  
"""  
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

println rootNode.Body.'*'[0].name()
```